# How to create NewActivity on Child of ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, expandablelistview

I created Expandable List View Men's and Women's sports. Under Men's and Women's sports we can select one of the sports. I got my children respond on click what gives me respond like "Baseball is clicked.". My question is how I can get NewActivity(open new page) after I click on the one of my sports(ex. If I click on the baseball that will open new page for me where I gonna be able to show results from previous game). `Here is my code:`

```
activity_main.xml:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/mtfinal" 
    >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:dividerHeight="1.5dp" 
        >
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>

MainActivity.java:

     package com.example.athletic_project.java;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity<View> extends ActionBarActivity {

        ExpandableListView exv;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            exv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
            exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));

            exv.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener(){


            @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                        android.view.View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                        long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String itemclicked=MyAdapter.childList[groupPosition][childPosition];
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, itemclicked + " is clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
    }
MyAdapter.java:

package com.example.athletic_project.java;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
Typeface typeface;

static String []parentList = {"Men's Sports","Women's Sports"};
static String [][]childList = {
    {
        "Baseball","Basketball","Bowling","Cross Country","Golf","Soccer","Track & Field"
    },
    {
        "Baseball","Basketball","Bowling","Cross Country","Golf","Soccer","Track & Field","Volleyball"
    }
};

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return parentList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childList[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/KGTribecaStamp.ttf");
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(parentList[groupPosition]);
        tv.setPadding(45, 10, 10, 10);
        tv.setTextSize(18);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        tv.setTypeface(typeface);
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/KGTribecaStamp.ttf");
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(childList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        tv.setPadding(45, 10, 10, 10);
        tv.setTextSize(15);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setTypeface(typeface);
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use child item click listener and switch statement To know which is selected

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    switch (groupPosition)
    {
    case 0:
            switch (childPosition)
            {
            case 0:
                Baseball();
                break;
            case 1:
                //do something
                break;
            }
      case 1:
            switch (childPosition)

             {
            case 0:
                football();
                break;
            case 1:
                //do something
                break;
            }
    }
    return false;
}

private void baseball() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, baseball.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);


}

private void football() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, football.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);

}   });   }
```

now create 2 class baseball.java and football.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class football extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.football_activity);

}}
```

---

```
 import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;

  public class baseball extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.baseball_activity);

}}
```

for now need 2 xml fill football_activity.xml and baseball_activity.xml
after creates these we need go to AndroidManifest

add these to AndroidManifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".baseball"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".football"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>
```

done ! :)

Comment: I have a question, I tried this code and every time if I click on Baseball my app stop working. If I click on any other sport nothing happen.Do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you start a new activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
this.getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
this.getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: What should I create under the class NewActivity?

Comment: You would just write the name of the activity you wish to launch.

Comment: Where I have to put Intent part?

Comment: You may not want to use the finish(), as I imagine you'd like to be able to navigate back to the MainActivity; however, you will put this inside your onChildClick.